# Having multiple Oscillators play together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, web-audio-api

I built an oscillator with sliders for frequency, detune, gain, waveform and a button to turn the osc on and off. By itself, it works exactly how I'd expect it to and want it to work. However, when I duplicated the code to make new oscillators for it to play with, the oscillators only play once even though i'm using `osc.disconnect()` and the waveform slider is pretty finicky too. From what I can tell, the problem is with my play/pause buttons when I call the osc on click.

This is the code: for my play button:

```
$('#play_pause_osc1').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc1") {
        $(this).val("Pause");
        osc1();
    } else {
        $(this).val("Play Osc1");
        osc1.disconnect();
    }
});
```

and the error I get after the first click is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'osc1' of object [object Object] is not a function

I get the same error for the other osc's as well considering they're just the first osc duplicated.

here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/YRsE7/1/

Answer (score 2):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/YRsE7/3/

You are using `ocs1` as function as well as oscillator object which is creating conflict.

**JS:-**

```
//WEB AUDIO SET UP//
//used start web audio
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext();
speakers = ctx.destination;
var osc1= ctx.createOscillator();
var osc2= ctx.createOscillator();
var osc3= ctx.createOscillator();

$(document).ready(function () {

    //WAVEFORM OBJECTS - used to set the value of "cur_wave_osc" under Waveform sliders.//
    var wF = {
        0: "Sine",
        1: "Square",
        2: "Sawtooth",
        3: "Triangle"
    };
    //PLAY_PAUSE BUTTONS - used to play & pause the oscillators.//
    //OSC1 PLAY_PAUSE//
    $('#play_pause_osc1').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc1") {
            $(this).val("Pause");
            oscillator1Start();
        } else {
            $(this).val("Play Osc1");
            osc1.disconnect();
        }
    });
    //OSC2 PLAY_PAUSE//
    $('#play_pause_osc2').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc2") {
            $(this).val("Pause");
            oscillator2Start();
        } else {
            $(this).val("Play Osc2");
            osc2.disconnect();
        }
    });
    //OSC3 PLAY_PAUSE//
    $('#play_pause_osc3').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc3") {
            $(this).val("Pause");
            oscillator3Start();
        } else {
            $(this).val("Play Osc3");
            osc3.disconnect();
        }
    });
    //GAIN SLIDERS - used for controlling osc volume.//
    //OSC1_GAIN//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_vol").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 0.5,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_vol_osc1").val(ui.value);
                gainNode1.gain.value = $("#cur_vol_osc1").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_vol_osc1").val($("#osc1_vol").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC2_GAIN//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_vol").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 0.5,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_vol_osc2").val(ui.value);
                gainNode2.gain.value = $("#cur_vol_osc2").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_vol_osc2").val($("#osc2_vol").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC3_GAIN//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_vol").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 0.5,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_vol_osc3").val(ui.value);
                gainNode3.gain.value = $("#cur_vol_osc3").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_vol_osc3").val($("#osc3_vol").slider("value"));
    });
    //PITCH SLIDERS - used for controlling osc pitch.//
    //OSC1_PITCH//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_pitch").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 25000,
            value: 440,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_pitch_osc1").val(ui.value);
                osc1.frequency.value = $("#cur_pitch_osc1").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_pitch_osc1").val($("#osc1_pitch").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC2_PITCH//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_pitch").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 25000,
            value: 440,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_pitch_osc2").val(ui.value);
                osc2.frequency.value = $("#cur_pitch_osc2").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_pitch_osc2").val($("#osc2_pitch").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC3_PITCH//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_pitch").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 25000,
            value: 440,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_pitch_osc3").val(ui.value);
                osc3.frequency.value = $("#cur_pitch_osc3").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_pitch_osc3").val($("#osc3_pitch").slider("value"));
    });
    //DETUNE SLIDER - used for controlling osc detune.//
    //OSC1_DETUNE//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_detune").slider({
            min: -4800,
            max: 4800,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_detune_osc1").val(ui.value);
                osc1.detune.value = $("#cur_detune_osc1").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_detune_osc1").val($("#osc1_detune").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC2_DETUNE//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_detune").slider({
            min: -4800,
            max: 4800,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_detune_osc2").val(ui.value);
                osc2.detune.value = $("#cur_detune_osc2").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_detune_osc2").val($("#osc2_detune").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC3_DETUNE//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_detune").slider({
            min: -4800,
            max: 4800,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_detune_osc3").val(ui.value);
                osc3.detune.value = $("#cur_detune_osc3").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_detune_osc3").val($("#osc3_detune").slider("value"));
    });
    //WAVEFORM SLIDERS - used for selecting osc waveform.//
    //OSC1_WAVEFORM//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_wave").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_wave_osc1").val(wF[ui.value]);
            }
        });
        $("#cur_wave_osc1").val("Sine");
        osc1.type = $("#osc1_wave").val();
    });
    //OSC2_WAVEFORM//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_wave").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_wave_osc2").val(wF[ui.value]);
            }
        });
        $("#cur_wave_osc2").val("Sine");
        osc2.type = $("#osc2_wave").val();
    });
    //OSC3_WAVEFORM//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_wave").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_wave_osc3").val(wF[ui.value]);
            }
        });
        $("#cur_wave_osc3").val("Sine");
        osc3.type = $("#osc3_wave").val();
    });
});

//CREATE OSCILLATORS//
//OSC1//
function oscillator1Start() {
    //creates the osc
    osc1 = ctx.createOscillator();
    //sets waveform
    osc1.type = $("#osc1_wave").slider("value"); //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    //sets frequency
    osc1.frequency.value;
    //sets detune
    osc1.detune.value;
    //creates a gain node
    gainNode1 = ctx.createGainNode();
    //connects osc to gain node
    osc1.connect(gainNode1);
    //connects gain node to speakers
    gainNode1.connect(speakers);
    //sets gain value
    gainNode1.gain.value;
    //plays the osc
    osc1.start(0);
}
//OSC2//
function oscillator2Start() {
    //creates the osc
    osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
    //sets waveform
    osc2.type; //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    //sets frequency
    osc2.frequency.value;
    //sets detune
    osc2.detune.value;
    //creates a gain node
    gainNode2 = ctx.createGainNode();
    //connects osc to gain node
    osc2.connect(gainNode2);
    //connects gain node to speakers
    gainNode2.connect(speakers);
    //sets gain value
    gainNode2.gain.value;
    //plays the osc
    osc2.start(0);
}
//OSC3//
function oscillator3Start() {
    //creates the osc
    osc3 = ctx.createOscillator();
    //sets waveform
    osc3.type; //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    //sets frequency
    osc3.frequency.value;
    //sets detune
    osc3.detune.value;
    //creates a gain node
    gainNode3 = ctx.createGainNode();
    //connects osc to gain node
    osc3.connect(gainNode3);
    //connects gain node to speakers
    gainNode3.connect(speakers);
    //sets gain value
    gainNode3.gain.value;
    //plays the osc
    osc3.start(0);
}
```

Comment: Awesome man, thanks. That fixed one issue. The other issue I'm having is, if you look in the fiddle, the 2nd and 3rd waveform sliders aren't showing up. They're the same code as the first one that works and they don't have conflicting names so I don't get it.

Comment: Do you happen to know why my other two Waveform sliders aren't showing up?

Comment: @ryanhagz - it's because of incorrect step value for those sliders.

Comment: I thought so too, but I fixed that 15 mins ago and no difference.
all the steps have been set back to 1. I've updated the fiddle to the code i have now: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/YRsE7/6/